# Can I load dynamically a module by ngload in karma tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test lazy loading module. Is this possible?
I have some code like this:

```
define(['app', 'angularMocks', 'angularAMD', 'ngload!app-filters'], function () {
'use strict';

describe('filters test', function() {
    beforeEach(module('app.filters'));

    ...
});
});
```

and I have an error:

```
Error: Load timeout for modules: ngload!app-filters_unnormalized2,ngload!app-filters
```